# How can I do jest.fn() in a object?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Hello I'm trying to do a unit test of these file but I didn't know, why is not working.

code file

```js
export const IssueTextItemComposite = ({ contentTitle, intl }) => {
    return (
        <p>
            <span className={styles['issue-item-content-bold']}>
                {contentTitle + ' ' + intl.translate('warning')}
            </span>
            {intl.translate('occurred')}
        </p>
    )
}
```

Test

```js
const enGBTranslations = {
    occurred: 'occured'
}
const intl = createIntlMock('en-GB', { 'en-GB': enGBTranslations })
intl.translate = intl.translate.bind(intl)

describe('IssueTextItemBold', () => {
    test('should return the content and occurred', () => {
        const contentTitle = 'foo'
        const expectedResult = 'foo ocurred'
        expect(IssueTextItemBold(contentTitle, intl)).toEqual(expectedResult)
    })
})
```

Error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'translate' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`props` is an object, try to pass them as one:

```
expect(IssueTextItemBold({contentTitle, intl})).toEqual(expectedResult)
```

Also `IssueTextItemBold` is a React component, so you might need to render it first. For example with [Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html)'s `shallow`:

```
describe('IssueTextItemBold', () => {
    test('should return the content and occurred', () => {
        const contentTitle = 'foo';
        const expectedResult = 'foo ocurred';
        const wrapper = shallow(<IssueTextItemBold contentTitle={contentTitle} intl={intl}/>);
        expect(wrapper.find('p').length).toEqual(1)
    })
})
```